# Appstore Connect RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: The request rate limit has been reached

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app in App Store, while I upload it give error:
**Appstore Connect RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: The request rate limit has been reached.**
This is something new from apple :)
Any solution for thins?

Answer (score 7):

Apple has a temporary outage today, which is throwing a bunch of random errors.
Just need to wait, until they fixed it soon.

See:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705658

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error today when trying to upload the app to app store connect from xcode, . My solution was that I retried the upload again a couple of times and it worked from xcode the third time around. It was temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree, I uploaded after some hours and it worked.